# Can I ask this question on templates used for layout in seforim?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

There are some questions on formatting seforim, what programs to use etc.. but I was wondering if I could ask the following question:

> I am writing a sefer with my own chiddushim on the parasha, and also a collection of "pearls" of commentaries, like old-seforim or seforim that are not often quoted. I am writing it in Microsoft Word, and would like to know if there are templates for seforim.

For example, most seforim have their first pages decorated like this:

[image]

Picture from [Greenfield Judaica](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/beis-meir-al-hatorah-ostovtze-2-volume-set-902192.html).

Does anyone know why most seforim have pages designed like a column and if there is a template one could use for his own sefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a question about an expression of Judaism - publishing Torah books, I would say that it is on-topic. It looks like as you've expressed it, there are two questions: one about the origins/meanings of the design, and one about practically how to utilize it. I would suggest posting them separately, as one needn't know anything about one to fully answer the other.

Comment: Thank you very much Isaac.